# When redirecting to Android browser, how to keep session?

Tags: android, session, redirect

In my app, when login to the app, it will automatically login to the server. now I have to redirect user from my app to android browser to finish purchase from webpage. But the problem is every time when i redirect to the browser, it askes user to login into the system again.

So my question is how to keep my session when I redirect from my app to native browser?

Here's my code:

when user log into my app, i use this to log into the system

```
HttpClient mHttpClient = GetMyClient().getInstance();
HttpPost hp = new HttpPost()
bla bla bla
```

and then after I login, i'm able to communicate with server within my app.
and then, i request system to send me a link of purchase, the link contains the username and other parameters, looks like:

```
http:// XXXXX username=XXX&number=XXXX
```

so normally, user is already log into the system, so when they click this link, it will go directly to the purchase page. but the problems not is I redirect this link to the browser or webview from my android app. It will go to login page again requesting my login. I know there must be some phpsessid involved, because now I'm just simply using

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,uri);
startActivity(intent);
```

to pass the uri to the browser. So anyone knows how should i do to keep my login state so that when i redirect to browser, it could go directly to the link I passed instead of login again?

Comment: Are you using cookies?

Comment: @greenapps i have cookies, should i send cookies to the browser as well? how to do this?

Comment: Maybe you only need the php session id. You can easily find out with FireFox on your pc. First login. Then remove all cookies and then go to the purchase page. Mmmm.. Could be that cookies in memory survive this...

Comment: @greenapps remove all cookies? let me try~ thanks anyway!!